# Python venv: automatically install requirements.txt when entering venv

Tags: python, python-venv, requirements.txt

How do I setup my virtual environment (`venv`) to automatically install all `requirement`s (`.txt`) upon activation?

###### Unsatisfying workaround:

I created a file `activate_venv.sh`

```
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

*Problem*: 
If the IDE automatically enters the venv, it does not use that file and will therefore not the installation.

##### Current solution

[Msvstl's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74937147/6702598): (props!)

> Add `pip install -r requirements.txt` to `venv/bin/activate`

*Drawbacks*
This solution is not system agnosic. You need to edit various files depending on the system you're on (activate, activate.bat, activate.ps1, activate.csh, activate.fish).

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: vscode und unknown others. This shouldn't matter. The solution should be IDE-independent.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your venv/bin/activate script and include the below line at the end of file

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Will this also work on windows or would I separately have to modify Activate.ps1, ... too?

Comment: @DarkTrick On windows I think we will have to edit the `venv\Scripts\activate.bat` file and add the command.